# Which mode is more security friendly, Active or Passive?

Tags: security, ftp

i was researching on the types of ftp modes active and passive and I am kinda confused with some questions with my current scenario

**Scenario:**
I have android devices as clients that will be used by an organization and the organization is very concerned about its security on its servers or data on them or anything else a good example is a bank server.

Now they can have like 1000-1500 android devices. each device will get a list of download items and each device will iterate through the list one by one and download that item and creating a new connection for each item.

Now looking at the concern about security and the number of devices with the above-mentioned FTP use case. I have the following question.

**Active Mode:**
According to my understanding, I think I should use active mode it deals with organization concerns about opening multiple ports on the server because the client android device will initiate both command and data connection.
but on the other hand, can the server manage to send or open a data channel to send 1000-1500 devices from a single port in active mode? won't it fail?

**Passive Mode:**
if I think about passive mode then we have to look for the concern about opening multiple ports on a security heavy organization. and in the worst-case how many ports should we open for passive mode for 1000-1500 android devices. the scenario of downloading files is mentioned above.

Comment: Some fundamental concerns: [FTP Must Die](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/FtpMustDie). Or just a rant, call it what you want.

Comment: Also: [File Transfer Protocol allows data connection hijacking via PASV mode race condition](https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/2558). Note even a patched server cannot fully protect against this. Frankly I don't know (yet) if FTPS is naturally immune.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FTP is using 1 control TCP connection and one or more data connections.

The control connection is used to transfer messages about what to do and what is doing on between client and server.
Data connections are used to transfer data.
In Essence: Client tells server on control connection: Give me that file and Server sends the bytes of the file to the data connection.

Since your question is security related, I'll dig a bit deeper here:
A TCP connection is "opened" by a client sending a TCP SYN to a server. These SYN's are usually the subject of firewall rules. Example: Allow <ALL_IPS_IN_THE_INTERNET> to connect to <MY_FTP_SERVER> on port 21.

FTP Active mode is when the client opens the control connection and tells the server to which IP and PORT the server should open the data connection to.

FTP Passive mode is when the client opens the control connection and the server tells the client to which IP and PORT the client should open the data connection to.

FTP Active mode is problematic, when the client is behind a NAT router, which is sharing one single public IP address between multiple clients. The client only knows it's private IP address and even if it could figure out the public IP of the router and sends it to the FTP server, when the server tries to connect to the IP, the request will arrive at the router, with many clients behind, and it does not know to which client it should to forward the SYN to.

A solution to this problem is Deep Packet Inspection. The router will recognize that the control connection is going to port 21, so it will take a look into the connection and when the client tells the server to which port it should open the data connection, the router will add a temporary port forwarding for that port for packages from the ftp server. The router will disable the port forwarding when the control connection is closed.

That's awesome and good as long as you don't care about security - meaning: THAT IS BAD. Always use encryption when authenticating or transferring sensitive data.

When you encrypt, the router can no longer peak into the control connection and hence cannot create the dynamic port forwarding for the ftp client in active mode.

That problem is solved by FTP Passive mode, since both connections are opened by the client.

But that creates another problem - not for the client, but for the poor server firewall admin. Since the port, the client connects to in Passive mode, is somewhat random, the resulting firewall rule looks like this:
Allow <ALL_IPS_IN_THE_INTERNET> to connect to <MY_FTP_SERVER> on port 21 and ports 1024-65535.
If you have a decent ftp server daemon, you can configure the range of ports used for data connections which make the firewall a bit better:
Allow <ALL_IPS_IN_THE_INTERNET> to connect to <MY_FTP_SERVER> on port 21 and ports 20000 to 21500 - that'd give you 1500 concurrent data connections.

You can do that, but I would recommend against that. There is a better alternative to FTP: HTTP.

- HTTP is not using control and data connections which is a blessing that doesn't come with real disadvantages.
- HTTP is well-supported by Security Devices / Firewalls / Web Application Firewalls/ ... - these products can even man-in-middle their clients SSL connections and perform content filtering on HTTPS
- Most HTTP servers can be configured to server directory listings.
- All HTTP servers support downloads, most of them even resume.
- An HTTP Client library is already available on Android and iPhone devices

So I'd implement the client like this:

1. Get a directory listing of the URL configured to list all files available for download
2. Download the files

HTTP even supports uploads and failed upload resume.

I hope I could successfully pitch HTTP here, because FTP is evil!

EDIT: I am adding a link to a nice post displaying the max connections in PASV mode behavior of vsftpd: https://serverfault.com/questions/563582/connections-number-of-vsftp-in-passive-mode

Comment: "that'd give you 1500 concurrent data connections' -- Possibly more. In general connections to the same IP:port of the server from different IP:port clients are distinguishable. In passive mode the FTP server does not know in advance the port of the client side and it may not check the IP; compare [data connection hijacking](https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/2558). But if the server checks the IP against the IP of the control connection (as it should to prevent hijacking to some degree) then it can support 1500 connections *per client's IP*, I think. Thus the total maximum will be greater.

Comment: I initially agreed with your comment and thought about correcting my answer. But my tummy did a rebel move. More than a decade has passed, since I last configured vsftpd. But I had that feeling, that the port range for pasv mode has an impact on max concurrent connections possible. A google did reveal that I was right: https://serverfault.com/questions/563582/connections-number-of-vsftp-in-passive-mode

Comment: Well, the answer there does not explicitly state the test was from clients with different IPs. I tested from different IPs. Vsftpd is indeed limited: in passive mode it doesn't allow multiple data connections to the same port, even if from different client IPs. It only allows multiple data connections to the same port on different IPs of the server. But it's a choice. Proftpd is able to handle multiple data connections to a single port, even if they originate from the same IP. I have tested. The question does not specify software, there is no reason to stick to vsftpd. "Possibly more" stands.

Comment: just one more question which i am still confused about in general case can single port i.e. data channel for active mode can handle 1k above clients request at a time? will it queue them or what?